# Como importar e exportar membros utilizando ECMAScript modules no browser?

Tags: javascript, import, export, módulo-ecmascript

Estou tentando importar uma classe, mas estou cometendo um ou vários erros. Alguém pode me esclarecer sobre?

Arquivo `js/calendar`:

```
export default class Calendar {
  constructor(date) {
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

Arquivo `index.html` (note que estou tentando importar a classe `Calendar`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calendar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <script>
    import { Calendar } from './js/calendar';

    var calendar = new Calendar('2020-02-01');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

No entanto, estou recebendo este erro:

> ```
> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
> ```

Comment: `import { Calendar } from './js/calendar'`

Comment: Eu já tentei isso, ele me retorna esse erro: "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Comment: No HTML `<script type="module">`

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa executar o seu código como sendo um módulo.

Um módulo em JavaScript é um arquivo ou simples script que contém o código JS.

Não existe uma palavra-chave em JavaScript para definir um módulo.

Mas em HTML5 existe um atributo na tag [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) que indica qual o tipo de script representado. É o atributo [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#type), cujo o valor:

- Quando omitido ou informado o Mime Type `JavaScript` indica que o código deva ser tratado com um script JavaScript padrão.
- Quando seu valor é `module` indica que o código será tratado em [modo estrito](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) e as palavras-chave [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) e [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) estarão disponíveis.
- Qualquer outro valor será ignorado pelo browser.

Em HTML5 apenas adicione o atributo `type` com o valor `module`:

```
<script type="module">
```

#### Diferenças entre módulos e scripts padrão

- Você precisa prestar atenção nos testes locais - se você tentar carregar o arquivo HTML localmente (por exemplo, com uma `file://URL`), ocorrerá erros do `CORS` devido a requisitos de segurança do módulo JavaScript. Você precisa fazer seus testes através de um servidor.
- Observe que você pode obter um comportamento diferente das seções de script definidas dentro dos módulos e não nos scripts padrão. Isso ocorre porque os módulos usam o modo estrito automaticamente.
- Não há necessidade de usar o atributo `defer`ao carregar um script de módulo, módulos são adiados automaticamente.
- Os recursos do módulo são importados para o escopo individual de cada script, eles não estão disponíveis no escopo global. Portanto, você poderá acessar apenas os recursos importados no script para o qual eles foram importados.
- Você receberá erros de sintaxe mostrados no `DevTools`, mas algumas das técnicas de depuração estarão restritas.

Leia mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules.